# Let visitors easily and quickly report broken website pages

Tags: reporting, forms, web

I am looking for a tool through which visitors to my website can quickly and easily report broken pages of this website.

I imagine the workflow to be as follows:

1. User navigates to a specific page
2. User finds an error, e.g. content, bad link, etc.
3. User clicks on an embedded button to report the type of error on this page
4. I receive an email notification with the report

I would like to use this feature mostly on WordPress sites but it would be nice if I could embed this code in any kind of custom-built website.

Regarding the code, I am fine with whatever code needs to be embedded as long as it is safe. :-)

Does such kind of service exist?

Comment: What would you agree to add to your website's source code? 1) a bit of client-side static HTML 2) a bit of client-side HTML+JavaScript 3) Server-side code

Comment: To add to Nicolas' comment (phrased differently): what kind of websites are we talking about? Custom built? HTML5? WordPress? .....

Comment: Thanks to the two of you for your feedback! I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend [BugHerd](http://bugherd.com) - I've only used it once, but I'm pretty sure it does exactly what you're after!

It embeds as a script into your site, and creates a "Send Feedback" button at the bottom right of the screen.

A user can then either select a portion of the page to report to you, or they can just report the page as a whole.

You get a report which you can categorise and action through BugHerd's interface, including assigning it to different team members if you have them. Each report has the details of who submitted it as well as the specific page and section it was submitted from.

It's generally pretty easy to use and looks sleek.

The only thing I'm not 100% sure of is your 4th requirement for it to e-mail you as I haven't personally set this up, but I would obviously be quite surprised if it couldn't email you to alert you of new submissions ;)